# Sukka - can walls extend past the schach

Tags: sukkah, schach

If my walls extend about five inches past my Schach support beams is that an issue?  Does the Schach need to "top" the sukka or can it rest a few inches below the top of the walls?

Comment: Although the law won't change, it would help you get a more complete answer if you specify what material you are using for _s'chach_, how much coverage you already have, and where the beams attach to the walls.

Comment: Walls are woods.  s'chach is bamboo mat.  Support beams are actually frame of slats that exists on the porch where the Sukka is built -- the walls of the actual sukkah rise above the frame on which I'd like to put the mat.  If you can envision the little crown on the aron that is what my walls would look like above the Schacht -- a small extra few inches going upwards past flat mat.

Answer (score 2):

In the mishnah it says that if you have a sukkah on top of a sukkah, if you can't use the upper one, the lower one is kosher. I would assume in that case the walls extend above the schach.

Comment: nice conclusion

Answer (score 1):

The walls may be higher than the schahch. It is kosher. It would seem that such a thing violates none of the laws of building a kosher Sukkah. Another proof to this (besides what Shmuly wrote about a Sukkah above a Sukkah) is that all walls which are at least 10 handbreadths tall (this is the halachic definition of a wall from a halachah l'Moshe mi'Sinai) are viewed as if they extend above into heaven (and certainly past the schach, if the wall is at the edge of the schach). This law is called "Gud Asik" (extend it above). For more detail, see Gemara Sukkah 4b.

Comment: ...**if the wall is at the edge of the schach**... Please note that _gud asik_ allows short walls to extend **up** to _s'chach_, but not up to mid-air. It is easier to "connect" _s'chach_ to real walls than to the imaginary extensions thereof by way of _lavud_. I.e. If real _s'chach_ is very close but not overhanging real walls, _lavud_ says that they connect anyway. Whereas if it is only close but not overhanging _gud asik_ extensions, _lavud_ doesn't work. [Citation needed and all, but please CYLOR.]

Comment: @WAF a wall that has nothing blocking it overhead, actually always extends up forever with Gud Asik. (That's why I gave a case of edge). I was pointing out that walls can always extend higher than the schach. IMHO your technicals have nothing to do with the OP.

Comment: I was commenting on the words I quoted from your answer, just because I thought the point about the edge needed clarification.